# how to run a shell script with export command in crontab

Tags: shell, cron, environment-variables

I have a shell script that **exports** values of variables when executed. The same values will be used in another script.
How to run this script(**test.sh**) in cron.

```
#!/bin/sh
export I="10"
echo $I
```

I will be using root access for cron.
I tried this command :

```
*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/backup/.test.sh
```

I checked with environment variables, nothing is updated.

Answer (score 3):

Why `.test.sh` if the script is just `test.sh`?

Anyway... exported variables life ends when the process that set it exit.

In your case the `I` var disappears when `test.sh` script exit

If you want to your scripts access to the `I` value, you have to `source` the `test.sh` file (e.g. `. /home/ubuntu/backup/test.sh`) and not execute it.

Otherwise you can set it into `.bashrc` file